# CoreData: Disk usage increases every time a NSData attribute is accessed

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, instruments

TL:DR - I have a NSData attribute where I save camera images and every time I access that attribute my disk usage increases.

Long Version:
My application has a Photo class that I use to save pictures taken from the camera. This is the automatically generated code for it:

```
@interface Photo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * original;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * thumbnail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * createdAt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Patient *patient;

@end
```

Both `*original`and `*thumbnail` have been set with `Allows External Storage` in the xcdatamodel file. Each photo object, after being saved, uses about 4MB of space. At one point in the code, I do this:

```
NSData *original = photo.original
```

For some reason, the first time the line is run, for each object, disk space usage by the app increases by 4MB. It is as if for some reason Core Data was duplicating and saving again the data contained in `photo.original`

I have no idea why this happens, and Instruments hasn't helped since the core data profile doesn't work with devices and the simulator has no support for camera.

Anyone has any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: What storage medium are you using for persistent storage? XML and SQLite are fairly human-readable and would make accountability easier.

Comment: Atomic? I didn't set anything in code, so it is whatever Core Data considers the default between Atomic, XML and SQlite. If I were to change that, how could I access the database inside my device to check what's happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds reasonable behavior to me. When NSData instances are loaded the system will try to keep that buffer in memory. But if they're too big, your data will end up in virtual memory, backed by cache files. On iPhone 4S, the largest image capture is 3264×2448, which can easily translate to the 4MB files you are seeing.

Change your Core Data model so that you only keep the file paths. Then keep the images intact as separate files.

Comment: I thought it could be cache, but they seem to never go away. My app is only 2MB, and after quitting it a few times and accessing the page with that code a few times, I ended up with over 1GB used. Do I have to manually clear that cache or something?

Comment: Have you checked the temporary directory?

Comment: You are right! There are multiples copies of each photo in different directories in the tmp folder. The oldest ones have only 1 photo, but the newest one has the 10 pictures I have taken.

Comment: Glad you sorted that out. I suggest you also change your NSData attributes to transient core data properties, so you can control the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Consider temporarily changing your persistent store type, [as outlined in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html). XML is a good choice for debugging, since speed isn't an issue. From there you can open your store file up directly and observe how exactly it's expanding.

Comment: That wasn't necessary in the end. I checked the database file in the app like you suggested, and it's only 176KB plus another 40MB in the external data folder. Erurainon was right on this one.